# Waiting for another page to load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

is there a possibility to open a new window with JavaScript and wait with jQuery until the new page has finished loading?

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
var win = window.open(url,'',windowSpec);
$(win.window).load(
    function () {
        alert('Finished loading');
    }
);
```

Comment: is the url in the new window on the same domain as the calling script?

Comment: Yes, it's all on the same server.

Comment: Can you edit the page loading in the popup? so to insert some javascript in it?

Comment: I tried it in the meantime and tried to access the second window with the following `$(win.window).load` and for the finishing of the loading. But it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the opened url is on the same server, it means that the two windows can communicate.

Add on the page that opens in the window

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var opener = window.opener || window.dialogArguments;
    if (opener) {
           opener.yourmethod();
       }
});
```

and on the page that initiates the `window.open` command use

```
function yourmethod(){
  alert('Finished loading');
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/nmXdc/1
(*the window that opens from the click is at http://jsfiddle.net/FPcMk/1/*)

Comment: The solution is good, but I delay the execution on the first page until the second finished laoding and with your solution I would use a `while(!secondNotFinished){}`-loop. But is there no possibility to do this with jQery in an elegant manner like `$(secondWindow.window)load()`?

Comment: @janus, you can do `var w = window.open(..); $(w).load(function(){..});` but it does not work in IE..

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a pity that in my company is the IE the default browser :( But that is the solution, I wanted. Thank you very much! :)